# load external files using ajax/query

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jquery

I'm having 2 buttons to load 2 separate forms, events and offers. when a user clicks on a button i want to load the relevant html form and make the buttons disappear.

> events loads events.html 
>   
>   offers loads offers.html

```
<div class="view_col">
    <form id="form1" name="form_b" method="post" action="">
        <input name="c_event" class="clr" type="button" value="event" />
        <input name="c_offer" class="clr" type="button" value="offer" />
    </form>
</div>
```

load the form to

```
<div id="form_body"> </div>
```

i want make sure that the buttons are disappear after the user has clicked.

Can someone give an idea how to do it?

Comment: Are the forms available in your DOM, but hidden, or do you need to create them or load them from an external source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$.load()` to get the HTML from your external HTML pages. Try something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="view_col">
    <form id="form1" name="form_b" method="post" action="">
        <input name="c_event" class="clr" type="button" value="event" id="eventsBtn" />
        <input name="c_offer" class="clr" type="button" value="offer" id="offersBtn" />
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#eventsBtn").on('click', function() { 
    $("#form_body").load('events_loads_events.html');
});
$("#offersBtn").on('click', function() { 
    $("#form_body").load('offers_loads_events.html');
});
```

More information on [load();](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery then this is quite easy:

```
$('#form1 input').on('click', function(event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  $('#form_body').load($target.data('url'));
  $('#form1').hide();
})
```

You would have to change you html into this:

```
<div class="view_col">
  <form id="form1" name="form_b" method="post" action="">
  <input name="c_event" class="clr" type="button" value="event" data-url="http://www.path-to-your-form-html-for-this-button.com/"/>
  <input name="c_offer" class="clr" type="button" value="offer" />
</div>
```